# What is bounded point evaluation property?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I read an article, it contains sentence like this - The hilbert space A possesses the bounded point evaluation property. What does this mean? I found this [Meaning of Point Evaluation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190136/meaning-of-point-evaluation), is it connected with that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the Hilbert space $A$ consists of functions $f$ defined on some set $X$, and for every point $x\in X$ the linear functional $f\mapsto f(x)$ is bounded on $A$. Such spaces are also known as [reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space).

---

*Remark*. Because the meaning of mathematical terms may depend on the context in which they are used, in general you will get a more precise answer by providing a reference to the source.

Comment: I am satisfied with this answer. The source is article "Riesz bases of reproducing kernels in fock type spaces" be Borichev and Lyubarskii.